# Modify generated json from PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I will be quick with more code less talk.

I have a mySQL DB and i want to generate json from it with PHP and PDO.

```
<?php
require("db.php");
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$rows = array();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '{"jsons":';
echo json_encode($rows);
echo "}";
?>
```

The above code will return

```
{"jsons":[{"date_time":"2012-09-06 20:55:44","name":"theOne","message":"i am god","ip":"","device":"HTC","device_type":"Phone","class":"class1","id":"1"}]}
```

I want to modify the php code so my json output will be

```
{"jsons":[{"date_time":"2012-09-06 20:55:44","name":"theOne","message":"i am god","ip":"","devs":{"device":"HTC","device_type":"Phone","class":"class1","id":"1"}}]}
```

The difference is that i want to nest `device`,`device_type`,`class` and `id` into devs.

I couldn't do anything or find from google such a task.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$push_in_devs = array("device","device_type","class","id") ;
$old_set = json_decode('{"jsons":[{"date_time":"2012-09-06 20:55:44","name":"theOne","message":"i am god","ip":"","device":"HTC","device_type":"Phone","class":"class1","id":"1"}]}') ;
$old_object = $old_set->jsons[0] ;

$new_set = new STDClass() ;
$new_set->jsons = array(0 => new STDClass) ;
$new_object = $new_set->jsons[0] ;

foreach($old_object as $name => $value){
  if (!in_array(strtolower($name), $push_in_devs))
    $new_object->$name = $value ;
}

$new_object->devs = array() ;

$dev = array() ;
foreach($push_in_devs as $name){
  $dev[$name] = $old_object->$name ;
}

$new_object->devs[] = $dev ;


echo json_encode($new_set) ;
```

Comment: my output(the json part) is ok.Cant remove the string(169) in front of the output. string(169) "{"jsons":[{"date_time":"2012-09-06 20:55:44","name":"theOne","message":"i am god","ip":"","devs":[{"device":"HTC","device_type":"Phone","class":"class1","id":"1"}]}]}"

Comment: worked like a charm.It was hard to beat! Thank Jari,thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Run this block right after the `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` line:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => value) {
        if ($column == 'device' || $column == 'device_type' || $column == 'class' || $column == 'id') {
            $row[$key]['devs'][$column] = $value;
        } else {
            $row[$key][$column] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will nest the values underneath the 'devs' key for each row, before proceeding to encode to JSON.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in file line 16(  foreach ($row as $column => value) { )

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
 $result = array();

  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

   if ($key === 'device' || $key === 'device_type' 
      || $key === 'class' || $key === 'id') {
      $result['devs'][] = $value;
   } else {
      $result[$key] = $value;
   }
  }
  $results[] = $result;
}

json_encode($results);
```

Comment: gives me a blank output. i inserted the your code just right after  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and delete my last 3 lines.